# How to search Crashlytics custom keys

Tags: ios, crashlytics

Using [their handy guide](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html), I'm able to set custom keys in crash data that appears in the Crashlytics dashboard for a particular crash. The docs (and placeholder text in the web site's TextBox) say you can search by key to find a crash like you can using other data like method name, line number etc. I can't get the search to ever find a crash by a key value. I've tried searching on both the custom key's name and value and it never finds it. I hard coded a simple key to the value "hello" just to make sure it wasn't a search case sensitivity type issue but no luck. Anyone ever able to successfully search by custom key?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Apparently, you just have to wait. 15 minutes or so after the crash had appeared on the dashboard site, the search by key value worked fine. Must be their search index service had to cache/process the new data?

Comment: Could you give an example of the format of key/value you used?

Answer (score 28):

In the text field that says `Search issue title, subtitle or key`, you need to put the search query in this format:

`key:<key> value:<value>`

eg

`key:id value: b329e5d2-dd2a-4bfb-95e3-1e5ffc9153dc`

Where in the code I've created a custom key named `id`